# Jquery confirm on delete using noty js is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-6, noty

I want user to confirm delete once clicked delete button( with class .delete)
I use Noty js and included its script src:

```
    <script src="{{asset('dashboard_files/plugins/noty/noty.min.js')}}"></script>
```

**The delete button with class   .delete:**

```
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger .delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>
```

**My Jquery function in app.blade to let user confirm delete or cancel:**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','.delete', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var that = $this
            var n = new Noty({
                text:'Confirm deleting record',
                killer:true,
                buttons:[
                    Noty.button('yes', 'btn btn-danger mr-2', function(){
                        that.closest('form').submit()
                    }),
                    Noty.button('no','btn btn-danger',function(){
                        n.close()
                    }),
                ]

            })  //end of var n
            n.show();
        });  //end of onclick
    });  //end of ready fn
</script>
```

Deep thanks;

Answer (score 1):

Your class name has a '.' in 'delete'.
Change it to

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>`

and it should work.

Comment: Solved when I put                   var that = $(this);    before                     var n = new Noty({